# How to Prove $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\cos\frac{2n\pi}{3} = 0$?

Tags: summation

I'm having a hard time wraping my head around this.

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\cos\frac{2n\pi}{3} = 0$$

Comment: The terms don't converge to $0$, so it's a divergent series. In what sense should the equality hold?

Comment: Sorry I had the question wrong. Edited

Answer (score 3):

The sum $\sum_{j = -n}^n \cos \frac{2j \pi }{3}$ can be -1, 1, or 0, depending on the remainder of $n$ when divided by 3. So there is no reasonable way in which this series converges.

Answer (score 0):

This series does not converge ! Use the link to check !

http://www.wolframalpha.com/widget/widgetPopup.jsp?p=v&id=dfaf1b7d15e572ae5a1b2fa172ce8657&title=Math+Help+Boards%3A+Sum+Calculator&theme=blue

Comment: Wolfram Alpha is a great site. But it is no substitute for a logical argument given here, on the MSE site, by a thinking human being.

Answer (score 0):

The series doesn't converge.
$\therefore$ you can't prove anything.